# C++ string concatenation

Tags: c++, string

I do Exercise 6 in Chapter 2 from book Thinking In C++, 2nd Edition, Volume 1 ©2000 by Bruce Eckel.

Original problem:

> Change Fillvector.cpp so that it concatenates all the elements in the vector into a single string before printing it out, but don’t try to add line numbering.

The file **Fillvector.cpp** is available at http://www.BruceEckel.com.

The following code is what I wrote to solve the exercise:

```
// Fillvector.cpp
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    ifstream in("Fillvector.cpp");
    string line, ss;

    while (getline(in, line)) {
        v.push_back(line);
    }

    for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        ss += v[i];
    }

    cout << ss;

    return 0;
}
```

The code compiled successfully and I got the produced result:

> }   return 0;s;[i];ing>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {

The output was not what I thought it should be. I thought the output must be as follow:

```
// Fillvector.cpp#include <string>#include <fstream>#include <iostream>#include <vector>using namespace std:int main() {vector<string> v;ifstream in("Fillvector.cpp");string line, ss;while(getline(in, line))v.push_back(line);for(string::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)ss += v[i];cout << ss;return 0;}
```

I read information about string concatenation operator at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/ but still do not know why the output is wrong. Please explain this output for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: what does Fillvector.cpp contain ?

Comment: Fillvector.cpp contains the source code above.

Answer (score 1):

You've done it correctly, but you opened the file "FillVector.cpp". To get the output you want, you have to open your source code's file. So if you named your program code "a.cpp" then you should open "a.cpp" to get your source code concatenated into a single line.

Also, on line 14 you use `string::size_type` to iterate over a vector. It should be `vector<string>::size_type`. That said, a simple `size_t` would do as well.

Also, don't forget to indent. (Lines 13 and 15.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ! The FillVector.cpp is source code's file itself. I forgot to comment about it. I changed it as you suggested, but it did compile error. I must insert vector<string>::size_type to compile successfully. The problem still there. The output I got is: 
}   return 0;s;[i];ing>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {

Comment: I actually indented those lines in my editor. But when I pasted all lines on question field, I manually format them using 4 spaces, as said by Stack overflow asking question guide, and forgot to indent lines 13 & 15. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You are running on windows and your output is :-

```
// Fillvector.cpp\r#include <string>\r#include <fstream>\r#include <iostream>
```

This looks more wrong than it really is, as the \r moves the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: This is totally the correct answer. The OP's output is correct, but the answers have all over-printed. Another triumph for Windows!

Comment: No, on _Windows_, `getline()` is actually smart enough to remove those pesky carriage returns. -- That said, it does appear to be what is happening...

Comment: I am running on Linux. This file was written using geany   . Now I understand what is printed. Thank you so much, mksteve.

Comment: @Dúthomhas: getline() on Linux is not smart enough.

Comment: "You are running on windows..." I know the difference between getline()'s behavior on Windows and Linux. mksteve's assessment is correct, because OP has a Windows-encoded file on Linux -- which is operator error and not a getline()/C++ error.

Comment: @Dúthomhas That is totally right. But I had changed all CRLF to LF, but the problem was still happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked properly for me (once I changed the `:` to the `;` as I indicated in the edit.  I got the result you wanted:

```
$ g++ FillVector.cpp
$ ./a.out
#include <string>#include <fstream>#include <iostream>#include <vector>using namespace std;int main() {    vector<string> v;    ifstream in("Fillvector.cpp");    string line, ss;    while(getline(in, line)) {        v.push_back(line);    }    for(string::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)  {        ss += v[i];    }    cout << ss;    return 0;}$
```

Here is your code with better indentation:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    ifstream in("Fillvector.cpp");
    string line, ss;

    while(getline(in, line)) {
        v.push_back(line);
    }
    for(string::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)  {
        ss += v[i];
    }

    cout << ss;

    return 0;
}
```

However, if you want your code to produce sensible output on Windows, you will need to force a newline between each string. Try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    ifstream in("Fillvector.cpp");
    string line, ss;

    while(getline(in, line)) {
        v.push_back(line);
    }
    for(string::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)  {
        ss += v[i] + std::string("\n");  // Add a \n for windows!
    }

    cout << ss;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The colon is my typomistaking, so sorry. But I still got the wrong output as:
}   return 0;s;[i];e_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)  {
when compiling your source code. Strange !

Comment: The output was produced on Linux. Thank for your help,   vy32, I do appreciate it.